# Xamarin UI Test Click the 3 dots to expand menu and select menu item

Tags: android, xamarin

Tapping the visible menu items is not a problem for example while testing a Android application.

```
app.Tap(x => x.Marked("menu_home"));
```

However on some pages a few of the menu items are hidden behind the 3 dots and I cannot figure out how to click this during automation and the click one of the revealed menu items.

This is one of the layouts

```
<LinearLayout
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

And this is the menu portion that is usually hidden under the dots

```
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_menu"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_menu_menu"
        android:title="@string/menu_menulist"
        android:visible="true"
        android:showAsAction= "ifRoom|withText" />

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_menu_delete"
        android:title="@string/menu_delete"
        android:visible="true"
        android:showAsAction= "ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

Can anyone show me an example on how to deal with this please.
Many thanks

Kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so app.PressMenu opens the menu, now to figure out how to scroll through the menu items